# Fighting complexity in the model for the developer

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, model

I keep [learning PHP by reinventing wheels](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-unless-you-plan-on-learning-more-about-wheels.html) and this is my latest attempt. I want to create a Model. This is what I got so far:

```
<?php
namespace Module;
class Model extends \Library\Model
  {
  public function index()
    {
    $this->whatever = "test";
    $this->moredata = "This is some more data to test this out";
    }
  }
```

However I think it's *overly complex*. Going back to more vanilla PHP, why isn't this better for the final programmer?

```
class Model
  {
  public function index()
    {
    $this->whatever = "test";
    $this->moredata = "This is some more data to test this out";
    }
  }
```

I know many of the differences. However, they can all be alleviated in the back end. For example, with this (untested):

```
namespace Library
class Model {
  public function __construct($ModuleModel) {
    $this->ModuleModel = $ModuleModel;
    }

  // Allow overwriting values (as would happen by extending)
  public function __get ($var) {
    if ($this->$var)
      $value = $this->$var;
    if ($this->ModuleModel->$var)
      $value = $this->ModuleModel->$var;
    return $value;
    }

  // ...
  }
```

This is only for retrieving data, but more examples could be made about other functionality. I guess the question is, **Why isn't this done more commonly?** some frameworks that do it the 'hard' way:

```
// Laravel 4
class UserController extends BaseController {}

// cakePHP
class Ingredient extends AppModel {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized on the answer after writing the question, so I'll answer, mainly for future reference.

I am assuming in the question for this simple, first test example that a class only has some static data. A more real-world usage would be to interact with the database. So this could be base Model:

```
<?php
namespace Library;

class Model {
  protected $DB, $language;

  // The Model only needs the place where the data is stored and the language
  public function __construct($DB, $Language) {
    $this->DB = $DB;
    $this->language = $Language;
    }
  }
```

Then I can use the database in the child easily. That way, the extra `extends \Library\Model` doesn't seem that much compared with that `__construct()` and one of them is required for accessing the database. So the less evil = the good. Basically, **inheritance is not so much about the data as it is about the functionality that you get in the child**. Please comment if I'm wrong or you have any other suggestion about the code.